# How to add a PHP variable inside REGEXP in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to add a PHP variable inside REGEXP in mySQL

My code is like this

```
SELECT count(product_id) as totalCount FROM ref_products WHERE misc REGEXP '(.*\"level_id\":\'".$course_level_id."'\.*)'
```

Comment: And what happens then.?Is there any error.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all guys for their time & effort. Here is the correct answer i found. Please check

```
SELECT count(product_id) as totalCount FROM ref_products WHERE misc REGEXP '(.*\"level_id\":$course_level_id.*)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use a double quoted string ("):

```
$sql = "SELECT count(product_id) as totalCount FROM ref_products WHERE misc REGEXP '(.*\"level_id\":\'".$course_level_id."'.*)'";
```

Assuming you use a single quoted string ('):

```
$sql = 'SELECT count(product_id) as totalCount FROM ref_products WHERE misc REGEXP \'(.*\"level_id\":'.$course_level_id.'.*)\'';
```

Comment: This is working perfect in database. so i will use a dynamic variable in php as $course_level_id. Instead of "20" i have to give the variable.                                                        SELECT * FROM ref_products WHERE misc REGEXP '(.*\"level_id\":\20\.*)'

Comment: Its not a double quote string

Comment: Added the single quote sql as well

Comment: Might be needed to escape the double quotes in there. Updated answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(product_id) as totalCount FROM ref_products WHERE misc REGEXP '(.*"level_id":"'.$course_level_id.'".*)'
```

Comment: @RIADev: `not working` is not very descriptive. We don't know what you're thinking or the output you're getting -- we only know what you're telling us. So, please be descriptive and explain the issue.

Comment: Sorry..This is working perfect in database. so i will use a dynamic variable in php as $course_level_id. Instead of "20" i have to give the variable. The query is like this                                                       SELECT * FROM ref_products WHERE misc REGEXP '(.*\"level_id\":\20\.*)'

Comment: @Amal Any upadtes from you ??

Comment: You are using quotes wrongly. Correct format: '(.*"level_id":'. $course_level_id.'.*)'

Comment: @nick In php it showing error near '(.*"level_id":' --- Undefined level_id. So we need to escape the double quote. Refer my answer its working perfect. If you have any quotes then refer ronald answer